# Limit of parametric integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, analysis

I don't know how to solve this problem.
We define $I(a)$ as:
$$ I(a) =\int_{0}^{\pi/4} e^x(\tan(x))^a dx.$$
What is the value of:
$$\lim_{a \to +\infty } aI(a)$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Did you try the DCT?

Comment: The value is $\frac{1}{2}e^{\pi/4}$

Comment: At first i tried to calculate in analitically, then i tried to find the value using the dct (even if i'm unsure if i can apply it) and at last i've tried to find some inequalities that squeeze it to $(exp(\pi/4)$ but without succes.

Answer (score 1):

Write $u:=\tfrac12e^x\sin2x,\,v:=\tan^ax$ so$$aI(a)=\int_0^{\pi/4}uv^\prime dx=\tfrac12e^{\pi/4}-\int_0^{\pi/4}e^x(\tfrac12\sin2x+\cos2x)\tan^axdx.$$The last integral $\to0$ by the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: How can you use the dct if the function inside the last integral equals $1/2 exp^(\pi/4)$ when evaluated in $\pi/4$ (therefore it doesn't go to zero as $a$ goes to infinity) ?

Comment: @foggy4546 Don't forget the $\tan^ax$ factor.

Comment: Yes but $(\tan(\pi/4))^a=1$ for every real positive numer $a$ so you can't apply the dct because there is a point in the domain [0;$\pi/4$]  where the function doesn't go to zero when $a$ goes to infintiy. Am i wrong? Am i missing something? thank you for the answer by the way!

Comment: @foggy4546 That one point won't matter. If you change an integrand at finitely many points, the definite integral is unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Integrating by parts and using $(\tan x)'=1+\tan^2 x$:

$$I(a)=\int_0^{\pi/4}(e^x)'\tan^a x\, dx=e^x\tan^{a}x\bigg|_0^{\pi/4}-\int_0^{\pi/4}e^xa\tan^{a-1} x(1+\tan^2 x)\, dx$$

and therefore:

$$I(a)+a\left[I(a-1)+I(a+1)\right]=e^{\pi/4}$$

for any $a$. Now use the fact that $I(a)$ is decreasing:

$$e^{\pi/4}=I(a+1)+(a+1)\left[I(a)+I(a+2)\right]\leq I(a)+2(a+1)I(a)$$

$$e^{\pi/4}=I(a-1)+(a-1)\left[I(a-2)+I(a)\right]\geq I(a)+2(a-1)I(a)$$

This will give two bounds for $I(a)$ and you can squeeze $aI(a)$ with them.

Comment: where does that equation come from? have you already integrated by parts?

Comment: @foggy4546, Yes, that's what you get after you integrate by parts with $u'=e^x$ and $v=\tan^a x$ (since $(\tan^a x)'=a\tan^{a-1} x (1+\tan^2x)dx$)

Comment: @foggy4546, I added some detail.